# your account already has a valid ios distibution certificate xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

hello guys i am using xcode 6.3.

When i am trying to save application build in local machine i am getting following error message.

[image]

I am having option to create build with xcode 5.0 but i want to create it with xcode 6.0 or greater version.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `.p12` key in your system. Export your private key from your older mac and install in the newer one. Here is how to export the `.p12` file

Open Keychain and right click on the certificate to export

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all these certificates from Keychain and delete your apple developer account from xcode. Then, restart xcode and add your developer account again. Xcode will download your certificates again automatically.