# Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate How to resolve

Tags: ios

I am getting the error `Your account already has a valid iOS Development certificate` while trying to fix code signing issue. I am modifying the application which is already released in Appstore from new PC, the old PC not available now. I need to submit the next version, but getting error as above.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried the "reset" option? or the "import" option?

Comment: I didn't have exported file back up for import. And regarding reset, I am not well familiar with ios development, is this going to create problem with previous version which already on Appstore

Comment: It is Simply Saying that You have created a certificate on iTunes but you did not install it locally.Now You have to locally install that developer certificate.

Comment: So how can I install that locally as I don't have backup. I have tried as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513415/your-account-already-has-a-valid-ios-distibution-certificate-xcode-6-3, but not solved.

Comment: To fix it, Revoke Your existing ios distribution certificate in Member Center. After than, a new one can be generated in XCode. and this will not effect your app on iTunes.